# Why doesnt this go back to white?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to toggle the background colors on a div. It goes to green, but wont go back to white.

```js
      function ChangeClass(SelectedDiv) {
        var currentClass = document.getElementById(SelectedDiv).className;
        if (currentClass = "Unselected") {
          document.getElementById(SelectedDiv).removeAttribute("class");
          document.getElementById(SelectedDiv).className = "Selected";
        } else {
          document.getElementById(SelectedDiv).removeAttribute("class");
          document.getElementById(SelectedDiv).className = "Unselected";
        }
      }
```

```css
           .Unselected {
             background-color: white;
             width: 20%;
             height: 20px;
             border: thin solid black;
             border-radius: 4px;
             float: left;
             margin-right: 6px;
             vertical-align: middle;
             line-height: 20px;
           }
           .Selected {
             background-color: green;
             width: 20%;
             height: 20px;
             border: thin solid black;
             border-radius: 4px;
             float: left;
             margin-right: 6px;
             vertical-align: middle;
             line-height: 20px;
           }
```

```html
<div class='Unselected' id='Div1' onclick="ChangeClass('Div1');">Div1
  <div>
```

It changes to Green okay. And I tried it without the "removeAttribute" at first to no avail.

Comment: `if (currentClass == "Unselected") {` not `if (currentClass = "Unselected") {`

Comment: this is not enough code :/ can you post more please? anyway, are you sure that `document.getElementById(SelectedDiv)` is correct? i think you might use `document.getElementsByClassname(SelectedDiv)` and use `==` or `===` instead of `=` ;)

Comment: @messerbill OP is passing an ID to the function, not a className.

Comment: @putvande oh true, sorry didnt notice

Comment: It was the comparison operator. I got so used to a compiler catching things like that...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apart from the obvious error with the wrong use of assignment operator, you can write it better.

As you are overriding the `className`, there is no need to use removeAttribute so

```js
function ChangeClass(SelectedDiv) {
  var el = document.getElementById(SelectedDiv);
  el.className = el.className == "Unselected" ? 'Selected' : 'Unselected';
}
```

```css
.Unselected {
  background-color: white;
  width: 20%;
  height: 20px;
  border: thin solid black;
  border-radius: 4px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 6px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 20px;
}
.Selected {
  background-color: green;
  width: 20%;
  height: 20px;
  border: thin solid black;
  border-radius: 4px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 6px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class='Unselected' id='Div1' onclick="ChangeClass('Div1');">Div1<div>
```

---

If you want to support only modern browsers then

```js
function ChangeClass(SelectedDiv) {
  var el = document.getElementById(SelectedDiv);
  el.classList.toggle('Unselected');
  el.classList.toggle('Selected');
}
```

```css
.Unselected {
  background-color: white;
  width: 20%;
  height: 20px;
  border: thin solid black;
  border-radius: 4px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 6px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 20px;
}
.Selected {
  background-color: green;
  width: 20%;
  height: 20px;
  border: thin solid black;
  border-radius: 4px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 6px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class='Unselected' id='Div1' onclick="ChangeClass('Div1');">Div1<div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Correct the comparison operator

```
    function ChangeClass(SelectedDiv)
    {
      var currentClass = document.getElementById(SelectedDiv).className;
    if(currentClass == "Unselected")
    {   
     document.getElementById(SelectedDiv).removeAttribute("class");
     document.getElementById(SelectedDiv).className = "Selected";
    }
    else 
    {
     document.getElementById(SelectedDiv).removeAttribute("class");
     document.getElementById(SelectedDiv).className = "Unselected";
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You used a single equals sign (`=`), which doesn't check if both values are equal, but sets both values equal to each other. Right code is:

```
function ChangeClass(SelectedDiv)
    {
      var currentClass = document.getElementById(SelectedDiv).className;
    if(currentClass == "Unselected")
    {   
     document.getElementById(SelectedDiv).removeAttribute("class");
     document.getElementById(SelectedDiv).className = "Selected";
    }
    else 
    {
     document.getElementById(SelectedDiv).removeAttribute("class");
     document.getElementById(SelectedDiv).className = "Unselected";
    }
    }
```